# How to add scikit-learn and gensim into my libraries' setup.py?

Tags: python, installation, scikit-learn, gensim

`Scikit-learn` is a machine learning library that requires these dependencies, http://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools \
                     python-numpy python-scipy \
                     libatlas-dev libatlas3gf-base
```

before a user can:

```
pip install -U scikit-learn
```

And `gensim` requires no additional dependencies, http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/install.html and simply do:

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

I have my `setup.py` as such without `scikit`, its dependencies and `gensim` from https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/blob/master/setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='pywsd',
    version='0.1',
    packages=['pywsd',],
    long_description='Python Implementations of Word Sense Disambiguation (WSD) technologies',
)
```

How do I add `scikit-learn` and `gensim` into my `setup.py`?

Comment: How do you want people to be able to install it? For pip, a ``requirements.txt`` is the easiest way. However you can only install python packages this way, so you can not pull in the scikit-learn dependencies.

Comment: @andreasMueller, I wish that users can simply do `python setup.py install` but it's pretty hard given that my package depends on other libraries that depends on other libraries, e.g. `scikit-learn` and `NLTK` and `gensim`.

Comment: I don't think ``python setup.py install`` will ever fetch dependencies. For python packages with python dependencies, achieving ``pip install packagename`` is quite easy. That doesn't work for well for installing numpy / scipy, though, so installing the packages you mentioned in a roust way is kind of hard.

Comment: =( I guess I have to write down some download instructions mixed with some `pip install <package>` in `requirements.txt`.

Comment: What if I add all the source codes from different dependencies into my library? Would that be an overkill?

Comment: It creates a significant maintainance burden. Also, do you want to add scipy and numpy into your package? To compile scipy, you need a fortran compiler, so that would actually make installation more difficult.

Comment: after a month of thinking, i end up recoding stuff from some cut-and-paste work but it still a make-do solution (https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/tree/master/pywsd/merlin)... Is that viable? `scipy` is being pesky if it doesn't run easily across platforms and distro...

Comment: I don't see the solution you refer to. the link is dead btw.

Comment: sorry i moved it out of the other library, it's here now: https://github.com/alvations/pywsd/tree/master/merlin